# scroll through "stack" of DOM objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I have this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/72p0rkqd/

html:

```
<section id="contact"></section>
<section id="works"></section>
<section id="about"></section>
<section id="home"></section>
```

css:

```
section {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#home {
  background-color: black;
}

#about {
  background-color: red;
}

#works {
  background-color: purple;
}

#contact {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

which reflects my site

right now, the four sections lay on top of each other.
what I want is when we begin to scroll at the site, it will scroll through the stack of sections. When we scroll, it will first scroll through #home, so #home scrolls up, making #about visible, and when #home is not on the screen anymore, it will begin scrolling #about upwards, making #works visible and so on. When you then scroll up on the page, the sections should begin stacking themself again, reverting the downscroll process.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution I found. Maybe it's not the best answer and it certainly have to be improved.

I got it using animate() to move up/down the sections and "DOMMouseScroll" & "mousewheel" to get wheel moves from jQuery.

I had to use some flags to prevent from long scrolls.

Here is the jQuery :

```
var homeAnimating = false;
var aboutAnimating = false;
var worksAnimating = false;
var contactAnimating = false;

$('#home').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
  if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) { //alternative options for wheelData: wheelDeltaX & wheelDeltaY
    //scroll down
    if(homeAnimating) {
        return;
    }
        $('#home').animate({
          'marginTop' : "-=100vh" //moves up
        });
        homeAnimating = true;
        aboutAnimating = false;
  }
  //prevent page from scrolling
  return false;
});

$('#about').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
  if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) { //alternative options for wheelData: wheelDeltaX & wheelDeltaY
    //scroll down
    if(aboutAnimating) {
        return;
    }
       $('#about').animate({
         'marginTop' : "-=100vh" //moves up
       });
       aboutAnimating = true;
       worksAnimating = false;
  } else {
    //scroll up
    if(aboutAnimating) {
        return;
    }
       $('#home').animate({
         'marginTop' : "+=100vh" //moves down
       });
       aboutAnimating = true;
       homeAnimating = false;
  }
  //prevent page fom scrolling
  return false;
});

$('#works').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
  if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) { //alternative options for wheelData: wheelDeltaX & wheelDeltaY
    //scroll down
    if(worksAnimating) {
        return;
    }
        $('#works').animate({
          'marginTop' : "-=100vh" //moves up
        });
        worksAnimating = true;
        contactAnimating = false;
  } else {
    //scroll up
    if(worksAnimating) {
        return;
    }
       $('#about').animate({
         'marginTop' : "+=100vh" //moves down
       });
       aboutAnimating = false;
       worksAnimating = true;
  }
  //prevent page fom scrolling
  return false;
});

$('#contact').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
  if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) { //alternative options for wheelData: wheelDeltaX & wheelDeltaY
  } else {
    //scroll up
    if(contactAnimating) {
        return;
    }
        $('#works').animate({
          'marginTop' : "+=100vh" //moves down
        });
        contactAnimating = true;
        worksAnimating = false;
  }
  //prevent page fom scrolling
  return false;
});
```

And here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fkahogqd/

Hope it helps.

## EDIT

Ok, that was a little tricky but I assume that's what you're looking for :

Here is the new jQuery :

```
var winHeight = $(window).height();

$('section').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
  if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
  
    var homePos = parseInt($('#home').css('marginTop'),10);
    var aboutPos = parseInt($('#about').css('marginTop'),10);
    var worksPos = parseInt($('#works').css('marginTop'),10)

    //scroll down
        $('#home').animate({
          'marginTop' : "-=5vh" //moves up
        },2);
        if (homePos <= - winHeight) {
            $('#home').stop();
          $('#about').animate({
            'marginTop' : "-=5vh"
          },2);
        }
        if (aboutPos <= - winHeight) {
            $('#about').stop();
          $('#works').animate({
            'marginTop' : "-=5vh"
          },2);
        }
        if (worksPos <= - winHeight) {
            $('#works').stop();
        }
  } else {

        var homePos = parseInt($('#home').css('marginTop'),10);
        var aboutPos = parseInt($('#about').css('marginTop'),10);
        var worksPos = parseInt($('#works').css('marginTop'),10)

        $('#works').animate({
          'marginTop' : "+=5vh" //moves up
        },2);
        if (worksPos >= 0) {
            $('#works').stop();
          $('#about').animate({
            'marginTop' : "+=5vh"
          },2);
        }
        if (aboutPos >= 0) {
            $('#about').stop();
          $('#home').animate({
            'marginTop' : "+=5vh"
          },2);
        }
        if (homePos >= 0) {
            $('#home').stop();
        }           
  }
});
```

And here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fkahogqd/5/

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's almost what i want :)

though I want the animation to follow the scroll, so as I scroll the page slides up, as if I was scrolling on a normal page, while in your example the pages just go straight up when I just scroll the mousewheel one click.

Comment: @Tomas0206 Hi, I edited my answer to scroll sections as you liked. Hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for :D Just gonna play with it a little, to make the code prettier, but many thanks :D